# iPhone - MKOverlay and MKOverlayView logic

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkmapview, overlay, mkoverlay

There's a point I wonder, maybe someone could explain me with simple words better than the doc do...

When you want to add an overlay onto a MKMapView, you first add something that follow the MKOverlay protocol.

Then later, `(MKOverlayView*)mapView:(MKMapView*)mapView viewForOverlay:(id)overlay` is called and you must return a MKOverlayView or something that inherits it.

What is the role of the overlay added in `addOverlay` as it does not display anything ? Why not directly add a subview as it's done with addSubview for views and put "inside it" the needed vars for the display ? Why running with such a 2 part process ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [model-view-controller (MVC) pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), objects that store data are isolated from objects that handle presentation: The role of the object that implements MKOverlay is to manage data storage, and the role of the MKOverlayView object is to handle presentation on a map.

For instance, you might have an `ApartmentBuilding` object that stores data about tenants, rents, property taxes, and so on, and you might want to use that object in an app that displays your real estate empire on a map – but you might *also* want to use the same `ApartmentBuilding` data in an app that calculates your tax bill, or that produces a calendar of scheduled maintenance.

If the code that models your `ApartmentBuilding` is cleanly separated from the code that displays your building on a map, then you can pair up your `ApartmentBuilding` model with a different view object – a `MaintenanceCalendarView`, say, or a `TaxSpreadsheetView` – and your code is easier to maintain and re-use.

Comment: Uhhhh... I understand MVC, but here, I don't. Easy to take a general example, but could you do the same for the overlay please ? Because i really don't see. I mean, the overlay MUST know the data it will draw. As UIView does. But I don't see anything like this for UIView management. Why such a difference beetween UIVoew and MKOverlayView ?

Comment: It's also possible to have an object that implements the MKOverlay protocol, say a `Glacier` object, that has multiple MKOverlayViews associated with it - an overlay that shows the glacier's size in 1920, in 1950, in 1970, and so on. Under MVC the model object doesn't "know" which view to display, and it's up to the controller to display the appropriate view.

Comment: No, no, your demonstration is not logic. You wouldn't say that talking about an UIView. There's no controller here. Just a View that displays something onto a map. If you had to do the same with an UIView, you would subclass UIView, add it as a subview of the view you want to overlay, put all datas into that subclassed view, and use that data with drawRect. You would never add something like a MKOverlay before adding the View. Isn't it ?

Comment: The MKOverlay object is not stage one of your view object – the MKOverlay object is your *model*. The MKOverlay protocol is a contract that says "this model contains latitude and longitude data", but an object that implements MKOverlay is still a model: It's a box full of data and doesn't contain any drawing code. The MKOverlayView is your (one and only) UIView equivalent, and the object that implements `mapView:viewForOverlay:` is providing your controller logic, serving up views (MKOverlayViews) for your models (MKOverlays) as needed.

Comment: OK, I follow you on that point, but saying that, we are saying that the UIView model (and any UIsometingView) is not MVC, as it hold drawing method AND datas that are supposed to be drawn ? Isn't it ?

Comment: A view object keeps a local copy of the data it needs to do its job, but most view objects (a UISlider, for instance) only keep a small subset of your model's data, and typically a view object has a short lifecycle and isn't a candidate for long-term data storage. In the case with MKOverlay and MKOverlayView, though, it's possible to have a view that needs to know literally all the data in your model, and that has a lifespan nearly as long as the model, to the point where you'd start to ask why your "model" and "view" look so much alike.

Comment: Thank you for those detailed explanations